# Como separar por columnas una lista

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Mi MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS=" 0,0,0,0"
                Android="0,0,0,0"
                WinPhone="12,10,12,10"></OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>

<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="EmployeeViewList" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0,0,0,1">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**mi MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace rargMobile
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Rob Finnerty" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Bill Wrestler" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 4, Name = "Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 5, Name = "Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 6, Name = "Sheri Spruce" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { Id = 7, Name = "Burt Indybrick" });
            EmployeeViewList.ItemsSource = employees;

        }
    }
}
```

**Quiero mostrar mi lista de esta manera** esto lo hice en windowsform con el mismo metodo, modelo y datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto es a lo que pude llegar** duplique la ultima columna para que vean que no se separan por celdas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Este es otro intento***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***¿Existe otro metodo para poder separar por columnas?***

Comment: retracto mi comentario anterior despeus de releer tu codigo. Estas metiendo todo en un stackpanel, por lo cual, columnas tenes una sola. no deberias encolumnarlo?

Comment: No se en Xamarin ya que no lo controlo, pero lo que debes hacer en principio es crear un Layout personalizado para cada Item de lista. Creo que en Xamarin se utiliza `ListView.ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

Buenas en este caso quieres hacer una tabla por lo que me parece que puedes usar Grid.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Puedes observar que creo una fila y tres columnas como lo que quieres.

Por lo que que quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="EmployeeViewList" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                     <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    </Grid>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: me esta saliento errores en el [codigo ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4ol4.png)

Comment: Edito la respuesta. Los Label tienen que ir dentro del Grid.